# Eliminating left recursion (can't seem to get it)

Tags: parsing, recursion

I've got the following grammar:

```
S --> SaA
S --> bB
A --> aB
A --> c
B --> Bb
B --> d
```

Now, looking at the general rule for solving left recursion, I can say:

```
B --> dB'
B' --> e | bB'
```

But that's as far as I can get. I tried expanding `S`:

```
S --> SaA | bB
S --> SaaB | Sac | bB
```

But I can't get it in the proper form for the algorithm.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why you are trying to "expand" `S`. The form that it already is in,

```
S  -> SaA | bB
```

fits perfectly to apply the same transformation as you did to B. It'll become

```
S  -> bBS'
S' -> ε | aA
```

Now, you can expand that `BS'` if you want.

Comment: I didn't we could treat `bB` as "terminal". From what I read in the algorithm, you can only do the type of transformation you did if the term after the `|` is terminal.